# Is it possible to detect from where an app is requesting an httpRequest?

Tags: android

Supposing I have **two** applications, both requesting the same `php` file from:
**`http://www.blablabla.com/request.php`**. 
Is it possible for someone, as a user, to detect that those 2 applications are requesting from the same place?

Comment: Anyone can act as man-in-the-middle and monitor traffic as a wi-fi access point. You might want to elaborate on your concern.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way to do that using eclipse, to detect the responses, etc...

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in eclipse, there are tools available to monitor http traffic which you can install to monitor either the emulator or device. Not sure what you are asking unless it is what kinds of tools are available.